# Get selected value inside controller to populate another <select> in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, select, controller

**Requirement is to display the selected option inside controller and populate other select on the basis of currently selected option.**

Below the HTML code snippet:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
....
 <section ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in category">
 </select>
  <select ng-model="selectedSubName" ng-options="x for x in subcategory">
 </select>
 </section>
....
</html>
```

The controller used:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.category = ["Design", "UI", "Web Stack", "Unit Testing"];
 //Use Conditional Statements to populate options for the other <select> 
  i.e, subcategory

 $scope.subcategory = ["HTML", "CSS", "JS", "Java"];
});
</script>
```

Comment: I hope that `i.e, subcategory` line is commented or doesn't exist in the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-change` to trigger a function that populates your second list

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
....
 <section ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in category" ng-change="foo(selectedName)">
 </select>
  <select ng-model="selectedSubName" ng-options="x for x in subcategory">
 </select>
 </section>
....
</html>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.foo=function(category){
//conditional code to populate subcategory
}
```

Comment: $scope.foo = function(category) {
   //conditional code to populate subcategory
   if (category == 'Design') {
    alert(category);
    $scope.subcategory = [ "Design Patterns", "UML" ];
   }

Comment: I have added the above code, this is displaying alert with Design. 
But, **not able to populate** the 
<select ng-model="selectedSubName" ng-options="x for x in subcategory">

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle which worked https://jsfiddle.net/v6sxhbz0/

Comment: Thanks it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using categories/subcategories, may I suggest bit different approach.

First define your categories object like this:

```
$scope.categories = {
    'Design': ['Photoshop','Illustrator'],
    'UI' : ["HTML", "CSS"],
    'Web Stack': ['PHP', 'Java']
}
```

now you can do something like in html:

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in Object.keys(categories)">
<select ng-model="selectedSubName" ng-options="x for x in categories[selectedName]">
```

keep in mind this wasn't tested so might need some smaller changes, but if I understood what you need, it makes sense to have it in one object.